# How many of the first 242 positive integers are expressible as a sum of three or fewer members of the set $\{3^0,3^1,3^2,3^3,3^4\}$ if we are allowed…

Tags: combinatorics

How many of the first $242$ positive integers are expressible as a sum of three or fewer members of the set $\{3^0,3^1,3^2,3^3,3^4\}$ if we are allowed to use the same power more than once.
For example, $3+1+1=5$ can be represented, but $8$ cannot.
I can only think of brute force once again, but I'm thinking about whether ternary(base three) representations can help and if they can how can I apply it to this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such a number can be written uniquely (almost - see below) in the form
$$x_0+3x_1+3^2x_2+3^3x_3+3^4x_4\ ,$$
where $x_0,\ldots,x_4$ are integers satisfying
$$x_k\ge0\ ,\qquad x_0+\cdots+x_4\le3\ .$$
This is a standard "dots and lines" problem (sometimes known as "stars and bars") and the number of possibilities is $C(8,3)=56$.

However, we have double-counted four possibilities like $1+1+1=3$, and have also counted $0$ and $243$, which are out of range, so we need to subtract $6$.  The answer is $50$.